# How do I jump one section when I am scrolling down in React?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I wonder how to scroll one section to another using React, just like this web: https://www.stevenmengin.com/

Is there any specific technique I can use? or it is possible to do that using React Framer Motion? What kind of keyword shoud I use for googling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is here i believe. Try search for Full Page Scroll https://codepen.io/Online-web-ustaad/pen/oVxVgB

```
 *, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  color: #f4f4f4;
  background-color: #1d1e22;
}
.scrolls {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 1.25em;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}
.scrolls .center {
  font-size: 0.825rem;
}
.smooth {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #1d1e22, rgba(29, 30, 34, 0.1), transparent);
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
}
.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}
.header ul li {
  margin: 0 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}
.header ul li a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #f4f4f4;
}
.header ul li a::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.header ul li a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/15R3qZR2/london-3841024-1920.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
section h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  color: #1d1e22;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
 
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/y8dxwCwc/balloons-388973-960-720.jpg);
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/bYWmGqRN/2.jpg);
}
section:nth-child(4) {
  background-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/VLPjQvRM/4.jpg);
}

  .social
{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:20px;
  right:20px;
  background:red;
  font-family:verdana;
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:5px;
  animation:new .5s linear infinite;
  margin-top:-50px;
}
.social a
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:18px;
}
@keyframes new
{
  0%
  {
    transform:scaleX(1);
  }
  50%
  {
    transform:scaleX(.95);
  }
  100%
  {
    transform:scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @faudi, I got some hint from your answer, using `scroll snap`